# Django using SQL Server Table

Tags: django-views

Can anyone guide me, is following code is best way to write... I am new to Django.
Do we need to mention <<conn=pyodbc.connect>> always for all views?

```
<<<-----
`def locationmaster(request):
   conn=pyodbc.connect('Driver={sql server};'
                       'Server=DBVED1;'
                       'Database=DB_ITO;'
                       'Trusted_connection=yes;')
   if request.method=="POST":
      if request.POST.get("FloorNo") and request.POST.get("Building") and request.POST.get("Location") and request.POST.get("IsActive"):
         saverecord=SeatLocationMaster()
         saverecord.FloorNo=request.POST.get('FloorNo')
         saverecord.Building=request.POST.get('Building')
         saverecord.Location=request.POST.get('Location')
         saverecord.IsActive=request.POST.get('IsActive')
         cursor=conn.cursor()
         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO SeatLocation (FloorNo,Building,Location,ISActive) VALUES('"+saverecord.FloorNo+"','"+saverecord.Building+"','"+saverecord.Location+"','"+saverecord.IsActive+"')")
         cursor.commit()
         return render(request, 'locationmaster.html',{})
   else:
      return render(request, 'locationmaster.html',{})


def seatmaster(request):
   conn=pyodbc.connect('Driver={sql server};'
                       'Server=DBVED1;'
                       'Database=DB_ITO;'
                       'Trusted_connection=yes;')
   cursor=conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("select * from SeatMaster")
   result=cursor.fetchall()
   return render(request, 'seatmaster.html',{'SeatLocationMaster':result})`
```

---->>>